# Authentication issues - request.user and request.user.is_authenticated is not set

Tags: python, django, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, wagtail

1. I have a Django based application.
2. I have integrated this application with SSO (Azure AD) using the package python3-saml
3. The application URL is redirecting to Azure AD and returning the response.
4. If I check the “request.user” or “request.user.is_authenticated” there is no user details found.
5. For other applications using the plain Django configuration, the same Authentication mechanism worked fine but I have used Wagtail CMS which is causing issues.
6. If I assign “request.user” manually after successful authentication from SSO, “request.user.is_authenticated” still shows false.

   ```
   request.user=request.session['AssocID']

   print(request.user) #Prints the Associate ID 

   print(request.user.is_authenticated) #Returns False
   ```

Kindly help me obtain the details in request.user and set request.user.is_authenticated to true when authneticated.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure `django.template.context_processors.request` is in your settings `TEMPLATES`:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {'OPTIONS': {
        ...,
        'django.template.context_processors.request'
        ...
        }
    }]
```

Comment: Yes Dan, it is present in my settings file under TEMPLATES.
 'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },

Answer (score 0):

Where do you use the request.user?
in a Page Class or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the associate data you're just setting the associate info to the session variable. to authenticate the user first you should have that user in your custom user model or built-in user model. Once that is done, you should retrieve the associate's info and you should log in that user using Django's `login` method. [Django login()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.login)

Once login is done, you will be able to get `request.user.is_authenticated` as True.